# Where to set Content Language for email?

Tags: email, localization, translation

Sending HTML emails in different languages, such as English and French.

Is it a best practice to set the Content-Language header in the

1. HTML `lang` tag: `<html lang="fr">`
2. Email header `Content-Language`
3. Both

Comment: Is `Content-Language` actually intended to be used as an email header field? RFC 3282 only says "This document defines a "Content-language:" header, for use in cases where one desires to indicate the language of something that has RFC 822-like headers, like MIME body parts or Web documents". Having said that, Thunderbird does gratuitously insert a `Content-Language` header. Maybe other clients do as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You can set the `Content-Language` in the header. If your mail is a multipart message with alternatives in other languages (e.g. when you send a mail with translations), you can set a different one in the headers for those alternatives.

There are two RFC's of interest here [RFC 3282](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3282) about `Content-Language` headers and [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) about message bodies.

From [2045 section 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-9)

> 9. Additional MIME Header Fields
>
> Future documents may elect to define additional MIME header fields
> for various purposes.  Any new header field that further describes
> the content of a message should begin with the string "Content-" to
> allow such fields which appear in a message header to be
> distinguished from ordinary RFC 822 message header fields.
>
> ```
>  MIME-extension-field := <Any RFC 822 header field which
>                           begins with the string
>                           "Content-">
> ```

And from [2045 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-3) you can conclude that an extra `Content-Language` header can be set on every body part for multipart messages.

If you like seeing examples, the Mozilla comm-central repo (Thunderbird and other MUA's) has some nice test data with examples: https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/test/data

If you are reading this in the future, you may be able to convey the language in the character set [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231#section-8).